# pom.xmlで.envファイルで定義した環境変数が読み込まれない

Tags: maven

pom.xmlで環境変数を取得したいときは、`${env.JAVA_HOME}`のように入れますが、同じディレクトリに.envファイルを設置して`JAVA_HOME`の値を定義しても環境変数が上書きされません。

Javaのコード内は[java-dotenv](https://github.com/cdimascio/java-dotenv)を入れることで認識しましたが、pom.xmlでも.envファイルで定義した環境変数を読むようにするにはどう設定すればいいですか？